# Android calendar view

Tags: android, calendarview

I'm pretty new to Android development and I'm looking for a means of including calendar in my Android application, but I'm striking out pretty bad when googling.

1. Is there any way to use a default calendar kind of view in my application? (would be ideal since the UI would be familiar)
2. Failing at a built-in option, are there any good libraries out there with a calendar control that I could use?

I'm not looking to sync and all of that (at least, at this point), just looking to have a calendar view that I can display information to the user.

Answer (score 32):

I wrote Caldroid library (https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) that is simple to setup and have many features such as setup min/max date, disabled dates, select date range, swipe to change month, fully localized, support rotation properly etc. It's easy to customize the look and feel. Just to share if someone might find it useful :)

Comment: hey i used your calendar, and  its awesome. but i need to set events on date. like i need to customize date colors according to event they have at that date. Can you give me a little idea how can i accomplish that?

Comment: You can supply your own view for each cell based on the date, you can find it in the documentation https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid#allow-customized-cell-for-the-dates-gridview

You can find how to use it in the sample as well

Comment: I got stuck in this problem, can you please check?
https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid/issues/24

Comment: Yes I replied to ur issue

Comment: +1 for your good work

Comment: @VikasGupta Can you please tell me how you fetched all the events and displayed over to caldroid?

Comment: Sir how to make single row (week view) calendar using Caldroid ?

Comment: Can you please check this issue - https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid/issues/280

Comment: Great Job! Is there a possibility to dinamically color (highlight) certain arbitrary dates (in order to provide user with some app-specific info)?

Comment: Is this library supports vertical scrolling?

Answer (score 9):

I tried [android-CalendarView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html), Caldroid and later switched to **[android-times-square](https://github.com/square/android-times-square)** which has this improvements:

- Much faster switching to other months due to vertical scrolling (no pagination which responds slow in Caldroid)
- Indicators, highlighted dates (at least in [this fork](https://github.com/HannahMitt/android-times-square) for android)
- iOS version available with the same look and feel
- looks cleaner than the android version because months are clearly separated

  [image]

Just like Caldroid it is a part of [a productive app](http://corner.squareup.com/2013/01/times-square.html).

Comment: "Indicators, highlighted dates (at least in this fork for android)" - is this also possible in Caldroid? I am in two minds whether to chose caldroid or this one, and I need higlighting dates... Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK, there are no other way than implement your own calendar. So... what you would have to do is using a `GridLayout` with 7 columns and create a custom `BaseAdapter` to display data correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Android now provides three ways to incorporate calendars in your app.

1. [Calendar view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) for picking dates and such.
2. [Calendar provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) can be accessed to add and remove events from the OS calendar.
3. [Calendar intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intents) allow you to provide a calendar without having to get extra permissions or deal with databases.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works on API11 or later. It would be nice if someone created a good backport so you can support 2.x versions

Answer (score 2):

it is possible but not easy.
http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151&cpage=2#comment-52767

and

```
private void InsertAppointment(String strTitle, String strDescription, String strEventLocation, long StartDateTime, long EndDateTime, boolean bAllDay, boolean bHasAlarm){
    int tAllday;
    int tHasAlarm;
    if (bAllDay = true){
        tAllday = 1;
    }
    else
        tAllday = 0;
    if (bHasAlarm = true){
        tHasAlarm = 1;
    }
    else
        tHasAlarm = 0;

    ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
    // Calendar in which you want to add Evenet
    event.put("calendar_id", CalId);                //CalId                                  
    event.put("title", strTitle);                                                           
    event.put("description", strDescription);                                  
    event.put("eventLocation", strEventLocation);                                                   
    event.put("dtstart", StartDateTime);                                                          
    event.put("dtend", EndDateTime );                  
    event.put("allDay", 0);                     
    event.put("hasAlarm", 0);                                                                  
    Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");    
    // event is added
    getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);

}
```

a quick search on 
    `content://com.android.calendar/calendars`
will help get you started. but I'm not finished mine yet I just can't get the data out yet. but it is possible

Comment: Did you successfully add the default calendar to your app? Please let me know. I need some help on this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This library seems really nice and with a more modern UI (Material Design) :

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

You just have to import it with gradle:

```
compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.0'
```

And add it in your layout:

```
<com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/calendarView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:mcv_showOtherDates="all"
app:mcv_selectionColor="#00F"
/>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Philippe i m using above calender view.every working fine i need to set the calender year at 1990 how to do this?can you help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use the android calendar picker I have created, it is open source project and you can easily add it to your project.

https://github.com/sancarbar/Android-Calendar-Picker

Answer (score 1):

You can use MFCalendarView: https://github.com/MustafaFerhan/MFCalendarView

set multiple events;

```
ArrayList<String> eventDays = new ArrayList<String>();
eventDays.add("2014-02-25");
eventDays.add(Util.getCurrentDate());

mf.setEvents(eventDays);
```

and handle with MFCalendarView's listener:

```
mf = (MFCalendarView) findViewById(R.id.mFCalendarView);
mf.setOnCalendarViewListener(new onMFCalendarViewListener() {

    @Override
        public void onDisplayedMonthChanged(int month, int year, String monthStr) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(String date) {
            }
    });
```

It's very simple.