# How to display a calendar UI in an Android application?

Tags: android, calendar

I want to use a calendar in my application like the calendar in the image below.

[image: calendar]

I want this calendar UI in my activity. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Related/dupe: [Android calendar view](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3702998)

Comment: Does anyone know any library that extend Android's `CalendarView` which allows easy customization for Date's cell drawable? I see many suggested libraries but they implement their own Calendar View which aren't extending from Android's `CalendarView`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hehe. We've done this before: see  at http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/.

You WILL need to do additional styling work if you want to get that precise look and feel from your image: but that's what open source is for.

Enjoy.

Comment: can i set different color on different dates according to my need?

Comment: this page is not avilable???

Comment: Still there, as of today at least: will probably be migrating to Github after google code shuts down.

Answer (score 3):

I've written a simple calendar view much like the one used on google calendar app. I provides automatic scrolling and does provide simple way to customize the way it looks. It also provides a simple api for querying dates/listener for when dates are selected or when the calendar is scrolled. It also has a bunch of tests along with it. It should also be easy to change the look and feel because it uses android paint for drawing, so you can change it however you like!

https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView