# How to use Calendar in Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, calendar

I can't see any calendar in Android Emulator. I want to use event functions in Emulator. How can i use Calendar there? Anyone knows how to do this? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inbuilt facility in android emulator for calender control.
You can create your custom Calender control.

For More information about Custom Calender follow below link

[CALENDER UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080307/how-to-display-a-calendar-ui-in-an-android-application)