# Android Timepicker

Tags: android, timepicker

I need a datepicker like the below image. Can anyone suggest how to do it. Is there is any control available similar to this?

[image]

I googled a lot, But can't find one similar like this. Please help.

Thanks in advance,

Vijay chandar

Comment: Would a [picker](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) do the job or do you need a visual calendar?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make custom with the helpful gridview, I don't think so that such kind control is provided, below are some links which may help you.

[Custem calender with gridview in Android](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/)

[Calender Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html)

[how-to-display-a-calendar-ui-in-an-android-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080307/how-to-display-a-calendar-ui-in-an-android-application)

[Implement CalenderView](http://caughtinthemobileweb.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/how-to-implement-calendarview-in-android/)