# How to display calendar view in Android?

Tags: android, android-view, android-calendar

In my application I need to display calendar and some events on it, like on image below.
[image]

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080307/how-to-display-a-calendar-ui-in-an-android-application) topic, but libs described there doesn't fit my needs. I've also found this lib: [Extended Calendar View](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/extendedcalendarview/), but it works only on devices with api level 14 or higher while I need to support api level 10. 
Maybe someone know some library for solving this problem? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i referred this link to create something like that [link](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/)

```
/**
             * NOTE: YOU NEED TO IMPLEMENT THIS PART Given the YEAR, MONTH, retrieve
             * ALL entries from a SQLite database for that month. Iterate over the
             * List of All entries, and get the dateCreated, which is converted into
             * day.
             * 
             * @param year
             * @param month
             * @return
             */
            private HashMap findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(int year, int month)
                {
                    HashMap map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                    // DateFormat dateFormatter2 = new DateFormat();
                    //                      
                    // String day = dateFormatter2.format("dd", dateCreated).toString();
                    //
                    // if (map.containsKey(day))
                    // {
                    // Integer val = (Integer) map.get(day) + 1;
                    // map.put(day, val);
                    // }
                    // else
                    // {
                    // map.put(day, 1);
                    // }
                    return map;
                }
```

In the above code create Hashmap which contains date. and replace if condition with this(Make changes according to ur needs)

```
if ((mEventsPerMonthMap != null) && (!mEventsPerMonthMap.isEmpty())) {
        Set<String> keys = mEventsPerMonthMap.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            if (key.equals(theday + "/" + monthInNo+ "/" + theyear)
            && mEventsPerMonthMap.containsKey((String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(theday)))
            + "/"+ monthInNo+ "/" + theyear)) {
datewiseEventmap.put(theday + "/" + monthInNo+"/" + theyear,
                        (ArrayList<Appointment>)
                        mEventsPerMonthMap.get((String.format("%02d",Integer.parseInt(theday)))+ "/" + monthInNo+ "/" + theyear));}}
```

**Changing each grid cell**

```
if (datewiseEventmap != null && datewiseEventmap.size() > 0) {
            mNumEvents = (ArrayList<Appointment>) datewiseEventmap
                    .get(theday + "/" + monthInNo+ "/" + theyear);


            eventName.setText(sbf);


            eventName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.appointment_name_bg);
            //gridcell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calender_details_description);
            eventCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //eventCount.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calender_details_description);
            if (mNumEvents.size() > 1) {
                eventCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                eventCount.setText("+ " + String.valueOf(mNumEvents.size()));

            }
```