# Calendar View for Android?

Tags: android

I need to add a calendar view to my Android app.  I need the user to be able to select a date by tapping on a day in a conventional calendar that shows a whole month at a time, and he can navigate between months in some simple manner such as tapping a button or swiping.   I'm not fussy about styling.   This app runs on a smartphone-format device.

When I search on this in Stack Overflow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080307/how-to-display-a-calendar-ui-in-an-android-application) comes up first, and it says that there is no such thing unless you want to write your own or use third-party open source code.  But it's from 4 years ago.   I've seen more recent Stack Overflow posts alluding to a calendar view but without details.   Is there now, in 2016, an existing Android calendar view I can just drop into my app that's part of the Android SDK?  If so where can I see an example of using it?

Comment: It's there since API Level 11... Meaning over 3 years ago! Simply google for `android calendarview` - first result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`CalendarView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) has existed since API Level 11 (Android 3.0), released in February 2011.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WidgetCatalog/CalendarView) demonstrates its basic use.

```
<CalendarView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

---

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2013 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.wc.calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class CalendarDemoActivity extends Activity implements
    OnDateChangeListener {
  CalendarView calendar=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    calendar=(CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendar);
    calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year,
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    Calendar then=new GregorianCalendar(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

    Toast.makeText(this, then.getTime().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
         .show();
  }
}
```

[image: CalendarView sample]

And, there are many [third-party date pickers](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/27), some of which use a calendar metaphor.

Comment: Thank you!  I wish I could give you more than 1 upvote!