# Calendar library for android app

Tags: android, calendar

i am designing an app for iPhone and android app. When the app gets launched for the first time it hits an api and gets back a large database which is common for a year(365 days of events that get scheduled). In my app when the user hits a button the calendar gets opened to the current date showing the dates in a grid view. If the dates have any schedule they use to look in a green color and if no events it looks in other color. Likewise i have some other operations. in my iPhone app all the calendar view, dates color and events scheduling are done by a library.

In the same way is there any library for android apps, so that it will reduce my work a lot.
Is there anything available like that. Please give me a suggestion..

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702998/android-calendar-view/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- [`CalendarView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html)
- [iosched](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/)
- [android-calendar-view](http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/)
- [Android calendar view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702998/android-calendar-view)
- [material-calendarview](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview)

Answer (score 28):

Since this question is quite some time ago, probably you have found your solution. I share my solution here so maybe other can find it useful.

I wrote Caldroid library (https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) that supports rich features:

- Embedded as a fragment or shown as dialog
- Set min/max date. The date outside min/max range is marked as disabled
- Set disabled dates
- Select dates fromDate to toDate
- Client can listen to various events when user interacts with Calendar
- Customize look and feel

Comment: but how i add some holydays in your calendar..is it possible??

Comment: You can checkout documentation https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid#custom-backgrounds-and-text-colors-for-different-dates and https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid#client-can-customize-look-and-feel-of-almost-all-views

Comment: you have asked to do " If you see JAR mismatched error, replace your android-support-v4.jar to the jar inside Caldroid." what's the change on that libary. I'm using the Support-v4 for my app..Is this version is available in maven Repo? and how can i change the height and width of the Calender..can i make it smaller?

Comment: @Raghunandan please open an issue on github and add some code

Comment: @thomasdao the library looks promising but it is not maintained. And I tried to import in Android Studio. It is NOT RUNNING the sample application.