# Help! How can I create a calendar app for Android?

Tags: android, calendar, android-gridview

I have created a `GridView` to manage a Calendar application. The idea is that the user will be able to add text and images to specific days, and view events in the grid.

Are there any calendar libraries or built-in classes that I could use instead of `GridView`, or does anyone have experience using a `GridView` specifically for this (or a similar) purpose?

Answers with code would be very appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calendar library for android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974035/calendar-library-for-android-app)

Comment: @Selva Explain More please! Do you want the layouts? or functionality?

Comment: @Selva I'm really not sure what you are asking. One way to get back a lot of the reputation you have lost from setting a bounty is to make your question as clear and straightforward as possible. This way you may get upvotes. As it is, I'm surprised you don't have any downvotes because of how vague the question is.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of creating your own grid and attempting to build this calendar from scratch, `Android 3.0 (API 11)` has a built in [Calendar View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html). On the dev page, this view is described as follows:

> This class is a calendar widget for displaying and selecting dates.
>   The range of dates supported by this calendar is configurable. A user
>   can select a date by taping on it and can scroll and fling the
>   calendar to a desired date.

Although you cannot type directly in this `View`, you can allow the user to select the date, and using the selected date open a new `Activity` that lets him or her add text using an `EditText`, or choose a photo.

Comment: [Calendar View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) has many methods deprecated, API 23. Also, Calendar View is not so simple to modify to fit needs. For example @Selva mentioned she wanted to add text and images, which I do not find myself a clear method or way in [Calendar View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) to do so.