# Displaying calendar in android app

Tags: android, calendar

I am making an android app  in which I need to display calendar.. I have searched a lot but not getting any useful result.
I have also downloaded project of calendar from following link:

```
http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/downloads/list
```

But it is also not working infact giving exception.
CAn anyone help me how to display calendar. 
Any help will be much appriciated.
Looking forward for solution.
Thanks

Comment: what u want exactly to display calender?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calendar library for android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974035/calendar-library-for-android-app)

Comment: And there are lots of questions are already existed for the same topic. http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=android%20calendar

Answer (score 0):

DatePicker its standart widget i dont think that it is really problem

```
<DatePicker
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

...
// Required Java init code:
DatePicker dp = 
     (DatePicker)this.findViewById(R.id.widget27);

// for example init to 1/27/2008, no callback 
dp.init(2008, 0, 27, Calendar.SUNDAY, null);
```

see [this](http://www.droiddraw.org/) it can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a custom calendar for your app you can use below library.

https://github.com/ik024/CalendarLibrary

[image] [image]

Hope it helps.