# How to reduce size of CalendarView?

Tags: android, calendarview

May I know how to resize the `CalendarView` in Android? 
The `CalendarView` occupied more than half of the screen. 
I wish to make it smaller, perhaps 40% of the screen. Thanks.

Default CalendarView size in my smartphone, occupied more than half

[image: CalendarView]

My current XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.ada.landing.MainActivity">

<CalendarView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:firstDayOfWeek="2"/></RelativeLayout>
```

I tried another way to define `CalendarView`, but the overall height reduced but it does not shrink by ratio:

[image: CalendarView]

```
<CalendarView
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:firstDayOfWeek="2" />
```

Comment: post your xml here

Comment: @SripadRaj I updated my post. Hope you can help. Thank you.

Comment: I am facing same problem anyone has solution please help

Comment: use display metrics and give the size depends on the screen size

Comment: @RajeshNasit, I see completely other widget, when I use `CalendarView`. Can you point out how to get the actual widget that is posted in the question?

Comment: its inbuilt controller of android after API 11 . check it for more info https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html

Comment: If default Calender doesn't fit your need, try out other third part library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974035/calendar-library-for-android-app

Comment: @CHANHAUYEEN ,use this library instead https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView.

Answer (score 5):

I think CalendarView is not (really) resizeable because Android adapts the size of this view to allow user to have a great experience using this view.
I think the commun size is when use a DatePickerDialog.
[DatePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html)

CalendarView needs a minimum height and width.

If you really want to resize your calendarView, maybe try to resize(or scale) it programmatically with this :

`float scalingFactor = 0.5f; // scale down to half the size
view.setScaleX(scalingFactor);
view.setScaleY(scalingFactor);`

Comment: scalingFactor stretches date text as well that looks bad

Comment: So... as I said, Android optimizes this widget for a better user experience. Maybe you can try to extend the CalendarView class, find the layout and customize it (like txtView.setTextSize() ).

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of different ways you can go about shrinking the size of the CalendarView. One is you can manually adjust the size of the view in the .XML file you're using the calendar in. Another way is by creating a new layout (Such as linear layout), adjust the layout to your desired size, and put the CalendarView in that layout.

Comment: 1.   Manually adjust the size of the view in the .XML file: Is that mean I need to change the value of layout_height? I make the height with 200dp, It doesn't work.
2.   I created new linear layout with width 500dp and height 200dp, put the calendarView in that layout. The outcome is similiar with the first method.
I inserted my xml code in post.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:weightSum="5"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
                  android:layout_weight="2">
        <CalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:firstDayOfWeek="2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
                  android:layout_weight="3"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may help to reduce the size of your calendar view.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CalendarView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:firstDayOfWeek="2"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="Hello World hello world "
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Now there is a library which allows you to set the dp size into sdp (Scalable Dp) so that it will help in many screen size

**Gradle for that**

```
compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
```

Code Example Same above example but it will support all possible screen size

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <CalendarView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:firstDayOfWeek="2"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="Hello World hello world "
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want resize

```
 android:scaleY="1.1" -vertically
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I put code it reduce to 40% width of calander view .try this.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <CalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:firstDayOfWeek="2" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ratio is not maintained

Comment: so, what you need?as per question he/she want size 40% of screen.

Comment: I want rectangle calender with very less space occupied in height and width must be match_parent

Comment: i got to knew it is not possible. it tries to adjust font to specific size but after it cuts calendar view text so,we can accomplish functionality by using dialog. here we need to make any view whatever size you want .on click of that view it display one dialog where full calendar will display.now we can select date and month ,year.then On click of dialog OK button.it is dismissed.

Comment: @RajeshNasit Let CHAN HAU YEEN comment on the answer. As he has put up the question with bounty. And the requirement is upto him and not you I guess

Comment: @Stallion i have put bounty. he had justed asked question

Comment: @RajeshNasit Oh my bad... You have all the wrights in the world to comment and suggest :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried above all answer but not of work what exactly i want. Then later i have user [Material Calender View](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview).

In that we can give tile width and tile height as per as our requirement. if we want rectangle calender view with much less height compared to width, we can set tile width more then height. Thank you all those who answered.