# Android Custom Calendar and Reminder

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-calendar

My application will contain a custom calendar, and according to this calendar user can create events and reminders.

And the thing is, is it possible to create a custom calendar in android ?

(I mean I want to create events in my calendar and these events will not appear in main calendar in Android. Preferably user can also add these events to the Android's calendar.)

So my first question is, is it possible to create that kind of application ?

2-) Do I need to use SQL lite for this project ? or Android stores these information ? Because I want to make the user ables to edit and delete the events and reminders.

Any tutorials or open source projects can be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@osayilgan

Check this link :

Android: [android-simple-calendar](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/)

[Custom calendar dayview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858162/custom-calendar-dayview-in-android)

[How to display a calendar UI in an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080307/how-to-display-a-calendar-ui-in-an-android-application)

[How to implement CalendarView in Android](http://caughtinthemobileweb.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/how-to-implement-calendarview-in-android/)

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Using Calendar Provider from 4.0 you can read, edit and add events to the calendars on the device quite easily.

[Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html)

There are multiple posts on this subject, Simon sums it up overe here as well

[Simon says :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11157587/1165581)

Comment: Thx for the answer, but I will be working from API 8 so Calendar Provider will not work. For the other you suggested, It's not the answer I'm looking for. Instead of adding and removing events to main calendar I want to create my own calendar in android calendars database and manage it with my self. Any suggestion ?