# custom android calender view

Tags: android, view, calendar, hijri

how can i customize android default calender view, like month name and number of day in month?

i want to change these things, because i want Hijri calender view in my app

i dont want to make whole calender view from the scratch, like, http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/

i want to use base api, and base view, that work simple and good

so, what should i do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Custom Calendar and Reminder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458139/android-custom-calendar-and-reminder)